# Unfortunately app has stopped ! when i try to insert some codings into the mainActivity class

Tags: android

```
![error ][1]

package com.welcome.testingnew;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText username;
        final EditText password;
        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
        final EditText result=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);
        Button login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(username.toString().equals("thamarai") && password.toString().equals("selva")){
                EditText3.setText("Success");


            }
            else
                EditText3.setText("failed");
            }
        });
    }





}
```

Tried: if i run projetc with below codes it works fine

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); } 
}
```

and if i insert anycode  after the

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

like this

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 final EditText username;
            final EditText password;
            username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
            password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
            final EditText result=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);
            Button login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); } 
        }
```

it makes Unfortunately app has stopped problem please answer me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to achieve this. Here's the working code :

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:text="Status"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    TextView status;

    Button log;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String uname = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            if(uname.equals("admin") && pass.equals("admin"))
            {
                status.setText("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                status.setText("failed");
            }

            }

        });

    }

}
```

When app starts,

[image]

When validation fails,

[image]

When validation success,

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I got it Thank you @Yuva Raj

Comment: You're welcome. If possible, accept this as correct answer. It will be useful for future people who searches solution for this problem! :)